# Converting an image to DDS

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

What I need to do is convert an image from a jpg to a dds in WP8.

I have found a couple of libraries, but unfortunately neither are built for WP8 (example [DevIL.Net](http://code.google.com/p/devil-net/)

Does anyone have any suggestions how to go about doing this?

Comment: http://directxtex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DirectXTex

Comment: I need to do it in app, on the phone (preferably in c#)

Comment: It states specifically that you can use it in Windows Store apps.  Not in C#, but I'm guessing you can live with that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668945/convert-tiff-to-jpg-format/11669224#11669224 look also at [Image Format Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks. NOTE: DirectXTex is not supported on Windows Phone 8, because WIC is not available on that platform. The .DDS files it generates are suitable for use on Windows Phone 8 assuming the pixel format is supported by the device (currently Feature Level 9.3). ----Btw, Windows Store app is NOT a windows phone app.

Comment: Just chiming in: Robert is correct. Use DirectXTex to convert an Image to DDS. You'll have to do that server-side or at compile-time, but that won't work at run-time.