# Why converting big TIFF to JPEG has generic error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, gdi+, tiff, system.graphics

I used this code for converting tiff to png before:

```
 using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(tiffBytes))
 {
     using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(inStream)
             .Save(outStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
     }
 }
```

and it worked very well for all tiff files with any size and dimension until I needed to change this code and converting TIFF filse to JPEG:

```
using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(tiffBytes))
 {
     using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(inStream)
             .Save(outStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     }
 }
```

But when I changed the code, I get a generic error for uploading big tiff size. like an image with 21 MB size. (there are no problems with little tiff size).

```
"A generic error occurred in GDI+."
```

What can I do? I have no limits on the size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert tiff to jpg format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668945/convert-tiff-to-jpg-format)

Comment: Lots of interesting answers here: [A generic error occurred in GDI+, JPEG Image to MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream)

Comment: The image dimensions may be the issue as there's a limit at 65534 pixels; https://stackoverflow.com/a/13646902/1838819