# Split a Multipage TIFF into several JPG files

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, tiff

I have a Multipage TIFF file and i want a Xamarin.Android app to extract the frames into several images to be saved to disk. anyone can point me to the right direction ?

Comment: I don't think Android has native TIFF support, so you would need to write it yourself or find a library that handles it.

Comment: Is this kind of what you're trying?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11669224/461822

Comment: exactly  what i need. but for Xamarin

Comment: You can take a look at this tutorial which works on xamarin android. As a disclaimer, I work for the vendor of this library but it will solve you libraries. You can split a multipage tiff into any of the 150+ supported formats: https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/file-formats/windows/dotnet/console/split-a-multipage-image-file-into-separate-files.html